# hide all rows after row X

Tags: r, openxlsx

Is it possible to hide all rows in a worksheet after a specified row?

```
library("openxlsx")

# Create a workbook.
wb <- createWorkbook()

# Add a worksheet.
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "test", gridLines = FALSE)

# "Hide" all rows after row 37.
setRowHeights(wb, 1, 38:1048576, 0)

# Write workbook.
saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)

# inspect file size.
file.info("test.xlsx")
#              size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime exe
# test.xlsx 2621280 FALSE  666 2018-09-13 14:54:10 2018-09-13 14:54:07 2018-09-13 14:54:07  no
```

Seems very inefficient and seems to make the output extremely large (and slow when trying to open it in Excel). I assume it's not hiding it and in fact just changing row heights to be 0?

Comment: Yeah, you're correct, `hidden` isn't implemented for `setRowHeights`, retracting my vote to close

Comment: You might look into trying to set the `hidden` attribute for rows like it works for columns, but I'm not sure if simply setting the attribute is enough. This is how it's set for columns: `attr(wb$colWidths[[sheet]], "hidden") <- as.character(as.integer(hidden))`

Comment: Depending on what your workflow looks like, you could also restrict the visible area using the VBA `scrollarea` option. It's possible to pass a VBA script to `shell()` if you want to keep everything in R